# Distance between two coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through the exercises on online cnx book Algebra and Trigonometry [here](https://cnx.org/contents/E6wQevFf@11.1:tkzb2Sb5@9/The-Rectangular-Coordinate-Systems-and-Graphs).

If the coordinates on a map for San Francisco are $(53,17)$ and the coordinates of San Jose are $(76, -12)$, find the distance between the two cities.

Throughout this chapter I have been learning about Cartesian coordinate system, distance formula with Pythagoras' theorem and the mid point formula.

The solution provided is $37$.

With what I have learned in the chapter I cannot arrive at $37$. If there were $3$ points and the distance was a hypotenuse I could use the Pythagoras formula. But there are only two pairs of coordinates provided.

Given I know that San Francisco is north of San Jose, I tried calculating the distance between the $Y$ coordinates:

distance = $y_2 - y_1 = 17- -12 = 29$.

How can I arrive at $37$?

Edit. Adding my sketch to demonstrate my confusion:
[image]

I cannot see how the Pythagoras theorem applies since I do not know the length of sides A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance is $\sqrt{23^2+29^2} \approx 37$ according to Pythagoras, the $x$-distance is $23$ and $y$-distance is $29$ as you concluded. So did you use Pythagoras correctly?

Comment: I'm confused because I drew a right angled triangle on paper. One end of the hypotenuse is San Francisco, San Jose at the other. To use the Pythagoras formula I thought that I needed to have the distances of both the smaller sides? I can see you using the theorem and arriving at the correct answer, but how would this look if I was drawing the points on a triangle on paper?

Comment: @DougFir The hypotenuse is always opposite to the right angle ($90$ degrees), did you count for this in your picture? Btw, you did calculate one of the smaller distances, for $y$, correctly. Now do this again for $x$. Then 'plug' it in Pythagoras.

Comment: Added a sketch to my post to show where I'm confused. How can I calculate the distance of the hypotenuse if I don't know A and B?

Comment: @DougFir You do know A and B; A is the $x$-distance and B is the $y$-distance, as you calculated. Does this help you reach the final conclusion?

Comment: Yes, it clicked when you put it that way. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The distance $d$ between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is given by $d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2} $. Can you apply this?

(The formula is a simple consequence of the Pythagorean theorem).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Find the distances between the two cities' x and y coordinates and apply the Pythagorean theorem:

$$
\Delta x=76-53=23\\
\Delta y=17+12=29\\
Distance=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}=\sqrt{23^2+29^2}\approx 37\ length\ units
$$

You could use something called [the absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Distance) to find the distances, but in this case it is not really necessary as you could easily see that the distance between the x points $53$ and $76$ is equal to $76-53$ and the distance between the y points $17$ and $-12$ is equal to $17 + 12$.